# DropDownListFor com ViewBag e Dictonary retornando valor nulo

Tags: c#, mvc

Gostaria da ajuda de todos para auxiliar no seguinte problema:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
O erro acontece quando ele ainda esta fazendo as validacoes dos campos.

***Controller:***

```
        public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var vEmpresas = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        vEmpresas.Add("Matriz", "Matriz");
        vEmpresas.Add("Filial1", "Filial1");
        vEmpresas.Add("Filial2", "Filial2");
        ViewBag.Empresas = vEmpresas;

        return View(model: new Suporte { Empresa = "Matriz"});
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Codigo,DataInicio,DescProblema,Empresa,Solicitante,Atendente,CodAtendimento,CodChamado,Solucao,Status")] Suporte suporte)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.SuporteAts.Add(suporte);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(suporte);
    }
```

***View:***

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Empresa, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Empresa, new SelectList(ViewBag.Empresas, "key", "value",selectedValue: null) , new { @class = "form-control" } )
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Empresa, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Isso acontece antes de salvar ou depois?

Comment: Como assim quando está validando? Não ficou claro, chega a carregar a página com o drop-down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme falei nos comentários da outra resposta, o problema ocorre que quando ele retorna para *View* após a validação dos dados a `ViewBag` não está carregada com os dados.

No Código abaixo extrai a carga da `ViewBag` em um método e fiz a chamada dele nas duas `Actions`

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    CarregaDropDownList();
    return View(model: new Suporte { Empresa = "Matriz"});
}


[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Codigo,DataInicio,DescProblema,Empresa,Solicitante,Atendente,CodAtendimento,CodChamado,Solucao,Status")] Suporte suporte)
{
    CarregaDropDownList();
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.SuporteAts.Add(suporte);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }   
    return View(suporte);
}

public void CarregaDropDownList()
{
    var vEmpresas = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    vEmpresas.Add("Matriz", "Matriz");
    vEmpresas.Add("Filial1", "Filial1");
    vEmpresas.Add("Filial2", "Filial2");
    ViewBag.Empresas = vEmpresas;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tenta da seguinte forma: Cria uma classe chamada Empresa

```
public string codigo_empresa{ get; set; }
public string nome_empresa{ get; set; }
```

E logo em baixo o seguinte:

```
public List<Empresas> ListaEmpresas(){

 List<Empresa> empresas= new List<Empresa>();
 empresas.Add(new Empresa
        {
            codigo_empresa = "Matriz",
            nome_empresa= "Matriz"
        });
  empresas.Add(new Empresa
        {
            cod_setor = "Filial1",
            nome_setor = "Filial1"
        });
  empresas.Add(new Empresa
        {
            cod_setor = "Filial2",
            nome_setor = "Filial2"
        });
 return empresas;

}
```

E ai no controller, vc faz assim:

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
         ViewBag.Empresas = new SelectList(
            new Empresa().ListaEmpresas(), "codigo_empresa","nome_empresa");
        return View(model: new Suporte { Empresa = "Matriz"});
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Codigo,DataInicio,DescProblema,Empresa,Solicitante,Atendente,CodAtendimento,CodChamado,Solucao,Status")] Suporte suporte)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.SuporteAts.Add(suporte);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(suporte);
    }
```

E o dropdown fica assim:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.empresa, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Empresas, new { @class = "form-control"})
```

Comment: Isso não é nada muito diferente que o AP já faz, o erro ainda vai acontecer, e, tanto no seu código quanto no do AP, após o POST irá dar erro porque a ViewBag não está recebendo os dados novamente.

Comment: Depois do POST ele fez um `RedirectToAction("Index");`, ela não precisa da viewbag de novo, pois a viewbag somente é necessária na action `Create()`

Comment: Note que no seu código e no do AP tem um `if (ModelState.IsValid)` que retorna para View caso seja invalido. O AP fala também na pergunta "O erro acontece quando ele ainda esta fazendo as validacoes dos campos.". O que ele está fazendo com `Dictionary` não é errado. e na sua resposta não tem explicação do porque criar uma classe e mudar para lista.

Comment: Então basta adicionar o `ViewBag.Empresas = new SelectList(
            new Empresa().ListaEmpresas(), "codigo_empresa","nome_empresa");` no inicio do `HTTPPOST` que não vai dar mais o erro. Ou o `var vEmpresas = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        vEmpresas.Add("Matriz", "Matriz");
        vEmpresas.Add("Filial1", "Filial1");
        vEmpresas.Add("Filial2", "Filial2");
        ViewBag.Empresas = vEmpresas;`, se ele quiser mantendo usar o dictionary

Comment: Maikeaerosmith e Barbetta, Testes as duas formas mencionadas acima e ambas deram certo. Agradeço muito pela ajuda.

Comment: @CharlesAndrade, se puder marcar a resposta como certa e votar agradeço!